# can I do a restore controlfile from autobackup out FAST RECOVERY AREA?

Tags: oracle, backup, restore, rman

I know that I can issue the command `restore controlfile from "location_here"`. But there is some config that can I do for issue the command restore `controlfile from autobackup` even whether the autobackup of the controlfile is not in fast recovery area?

Answer (score 0):

Why not?

From [Database Backup and Recovery Reference 12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/RCMRF/rcmsynta009.htm#GUID-B5094E73-C26C-4FED-AE39-8C2E9540050A__I1017491):

> The default location for the autobackup on disk is the fast recovery
>   area (if configured) or a platform-specific location (if not
>   configured). RMAN automatically backs up the current control file
>   using the default format of %F. You can change the location and file
>   name format with the CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT and SET
>   CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT commands.

Comment: Ok, in my rman configuration I've altered the path for the controlfile autobackup (configure controlfile autobackup format for device type disk to...) , but when I try restore using restore controlfile from autobackup the rman does't find the controlfile autobackup yet.

Comment: Those configurations tell rman where to _write_ a backup.  When he needs to _locate_ a backup that has already been written, he consults the repository located in the control file, or - if available - the catalog.  When files are written, a record - including the full path used - is written to the repository.  You might try a 'list backup' (rman command) to see what is known.

Comment: But I'm trying restore the controlfile with the database in startup nomount. Is in startup nomount just read spfile right? In my case isn't possible to use list backup command.

Comment: n nomount, the only info available to the instance are the init parms, and none of them deal with backup locations beyond specifying the FRA.  Someone may correct me, but I don't see any way to restore without specifying the location when you are in nomount.

Comment: Yes, I guess that you are right. I made several researchs and I guess that is impossible restore in nomount without specify the location of the controlfile as well. Thank you for the atention!